# Using Google Play Music on Galaxy S6 WITHOUT starting subscription

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-play-music

This is so annoying. I am trying to add music to my mothers Galaxy S6 and play it with the default player: Google Play Music. But despite getting all the files onto the phone in the music directory, I CANNOT GET Google Play Music to do  ANYTHING but show an invitation to start subscription (besides looking into the settings).

Can anyone confirm that it is possible to use the player without a subscription - and possibly how to do this?

Comment: it's really designed to be a service; use a different music player instead?

Comment: It's definitely possible. I do it every day.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the steps below with Google Play Music version 8.19.7938-1-M:

1. Clear Google Play Music's data. Restart the app.
2. It will show some subscription plans (Individual and Family). Select "No Thanks".
3. The app will then ask the permission to access your media files. Click OK.
4. You will then be asked "Get unlimited, ad-free music". Select "No Thanks".
5. On the menu select "Music Library". All your music will be listed based on playlists, artists, etc and can start playing/listening to them.